# php - Get latest form value

Tags: php, html, forms

So, I have a website with a form, and I need a page on the website to always be updated with the latest form data.

Here's basically what I need, let's say that the page with the form is "mywebsite.com/form.php", and the page with the form data is "mywebsite.com/data.php". Let's say that the variables of the form is name.
Let's say that Jeff takes the form and for the name he inserts "jeff", so, the form would get the variables and redirect him to "mywebsite.com/data.php?name=Jeff"
Now, Let's say Dave goes to "mywebsite.com/data.php", he would get a blank page without the name variable. What I need is so data.php will always have the latest data from the form on form.php, is this possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll need to store the form inputs on the server then whenever someone sends the form, and have your data page read from where you saved the stuff. Simplest way would be to `serialize()` your data and then stuff that into a text file on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this data dynamically and permanently you will need to store it in the database. In data.php create a query that updates this information automatically on page load. You won't want to use sessions because the data will be lost when the user closes browser, the session expires, or they delete their cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with user accounts, wouldn't it be a lot easier to just store the data in his 'account'. So you can retrieve the data from the DB, wherever on the website he is.

For guest users, you can just store the form data in a cookie or file on the server, and store/edit/retrieve the data from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could [start a session](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-start.php) and make use of the `$_SESSION` variable. In other words, when the form is submitted in `form.php`, store the data as `$_SESSION['name'] = Jeff`, so that this can be retrieved in `data.php`. The other option is to insert the data into a database when the form is submitted, so that `data.php` retrieves the information from the database.